# Wishing for help to build MySQL complex query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 MySQL tables like -

```
**tblCampaigns**
campId  campName    startDate            endDate              status
1       Campaign1   2016-03-10 00:00:00  2016-03-17 00:00:00  active    
2       Campaign2   2016-03-11 00:00:00  2016-03-18 00:00:00  active

**tblServices**
serviceId   serviceName
1           Car Washing
2           Car Painting

**tblCampaignServices**
id  campId  serviceId
1   1       1
2   1       2
```

I have given option to add multiple services to the campaign through auto-complete selection. My requirement is, when user types in auto-complete to select service to add to campaign, only those **serviceName** should appear to the suggestion list who are not already added in other campaigns whose start and end dates are coming in between current campaign's start and end dates. I mean dates should not be intersect with other campaigns dates. Also that serviceName should not already added to the same campaign.

I have made half simple query like to get services which are not already added in same campaign -

```
select    tblServices.serviceId,tblServices.serviceName 
from      tblServices 
LEFT JOIN tblCampaignServices ON (tblServices.serviceId=tblCampaignServices.serviceId 
AND       tblCampaignServices.campaignId=2) 
where     ISNULL(tblCampaignServices.id)
```

First of all, is it possible make a single query to full fill my requirement. If YES, please help to build it. If NO, which is the best way to get this ?

Comment: Let's forget about the autocomplete aspect of the problem for now. Consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result.

Comment: Oh, and probably best to come without expectations

Comment: @Strawberry I do not want to insert or update anything. Just want to fetch Service Names as per the criteria mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query makes what you look for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT    
tblServices.serviceId,
tblServices.serviceName
FROM tblServices 
LEFT JOIN tblCampaignServices ON tblServices.serviceId=tblCampaignServices.serviceId
LEFT JOIN tblCampaigns ON tblCampaigns.campId = tblCampaignServices.campId
WHERE
tblCampaigns.campId IS NULL
OR(
(endDate <
(SELECT startDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)
OR 
startDate >
(SELECT endDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2))
AND serviceName NOT IN
(SELECT serviceName
FROM tblCampaignServices 
LEFT JOIN tblServices ON tblServices.serviceId=tblCampaignServices.serviceId
LEFT JOIN tblCampaigns ON tblCampaigns.campId = tblCampaignServices.campId
WHERE
(startDate BETWEEN
(SELECT startDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)
AND
(SELECT endDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2))
OR
(endDate BETWEEN
(SELECT startDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)
AND
(SELECT endDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)))
AND
tblCampaigns.campId <> 2);
```

It is quite complex, so let us look how it works:

First we join all the information as we need also the start and end dates to select the permitted services

We select all the services not in a campaign:

```
tblCampaigns.campId IS NULL
```

We select all the services in campaigns not overlapped with the current one, that is the endDate is lower than the startDate of current one, or the startDate is greater than the endDate of the current one:

```
(endDate <
(SELECT
startDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)
OR 
startDate >
(SELECT
endDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)
```

We exclude from the result set those services which are in campaigns overlapped with the current one, that is with startDate or endDate between the startDate and endDate of the current one.

```
serviceName NOT IN
(SELECT serviceName
FROM tblCampaignServices 
LEFT JOIN tblServices ON tblServices.serviceId=tblCampaignServices.serviceId
LEFT JOIN tblCampaigns ON tblCampaigns.campId = tblCampaignServices.campId
WHERE
(startDate BETWEEN
(SELECT startDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)
AND
(SELECT
endDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2))
OR
(endDate BETWEEN
(SELECT startDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)
AND
(SELECT endDate
FROM tblCampaigns
WHERE tblCampaigns.campId=2)))
```

We exclude those services which are already in the current campaign:

```
tblCampaigns.campId <> 2
```

As the result set will have duplicate services, because there are services in more than one not overlapped campaign, we add DISTINCT to the top SELECT to avoid duplicates services.

The query works also if the current campaign has the same startDate and endDate of an existing one.

Testing tables

```
 tblCampaigns
 campId campName    startDate           endDate             status 
 1      Campaign1   2016-03-10 00:00:00 2016-03-17 00:00:00 active  
 2      Campaign2   2016-03-11 00:00:00 2016-03-18 00:00:00 active  
 3      Campaign3   2016-02-11 00:00:00 2016-02-18 00:00:00 closed  
 4      Campaign4   2016-04-11 00:00:00 2016-04-18 00:00:00 active  

 tblServices
 serviceId   serviceName
 1           Car Washing
 2           Car Painting
 3           Car Maintenance
 4           Brake Replacement
 5           Gear Replacement

 tblCampaignServices
 id campId  serviceId
 1     1       1
 2     1       2
 3     3       1
 4     3       2
 5     3       3
 6     2       4
 7     4       3
```

With this test tables the result of the query is:

```
serviceId   serviceName
    3       Car Maintenance
    5       Gear Replacement
```

Which satisfy all the requirements.

Regards

Comment: "It is quite complex" that is quite an understatement

Comment: @White Feather - I did some formatting, but logic is correct. It worked for me. Thank You :)